# How do you show that an elementary embedding is an injective function?

Tags: functions, logic, first-order-logic

Show that an elementary embedding of an L-structure M into an L-structure M′ is an injective function from |M| into |M′|.

---

I have defined an elementary embedding of M in M' as a function f:|M| -> |M'|, with M,s satisfies an L-formulae if and only if M',f⋅s satisfies the L-formulae.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me restate the definition : $f : M \mapsto M'$ is an elementary embedding iff for every $a_1, \dots, a_n \in M$ and every formula $\varphi(x_1, \dots, x_n)$, we have $M \models \varphi(a_1, \dots, a_n) \Longleftrightarrow M' \models \varphi(f(a_1), \dots, f(a_n))$.

The equality symbol belongs to your language. In particular, for any $a \neq b \in M$, you have $M \models \neg a = b$. Hence, by definition of an elementary embedding, you get $M' \models \neg f(a) = f(b)$, whence $f(a) \neq f(b)$.

We have shown that $a \neq b$ implies $f(a) \neq f(b)$, $f$ is hence injective (as the name elementary embedding suggests).

Comment: Doesn't this require some sort of augmented language i.e to add a constant symbol for every element of M ?